# taking a picture at multi touch event

Tags: android, camera, multi-touch

I'm new to android. I am developing a simple camera app (using code parts on the internet). I want it to focus at single touch and take a picture at two finger touch. Focusing part works fine. but when i do the two finger touch, the app crashes. here is the log report.

```
01-04 04:01:01.015: D/CamTest(8650): focused success
01-04 04:01:07.343: D/CamTest(8650): focused success
01-04 04:01:09.109: D/CamTest(8650): X0= 484.5 Y0=482.8125
01-04 04:01:09.109: D/CamTest(8650): X1= 269.5 Y1=229.39453
01-04 04:01:10.117: E/InputEventReceiver(8650): Exception dispatching input event.
01-04 04:01:10.117: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1061)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1006)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.example.camera_overlay.MainActivity$4.onTouch(MainActivity.java:65)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2399)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 04:01:10.132: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8650):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.132: D/AndroidRuntime(8650): Shutting down VM
01-04 04:01:10.132: W/dalvikvm(8650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bcd300)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1061)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1006)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.example.camera_overlay.MainActivity$4.onTouch(MainActivity.java:65)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2399)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 04:01:10.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 04:01:10.257: D/dalvikvm(8650): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 5% free 9450K/9863K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 95ms
01-04 04:01:12.953: I/Process(8650): Sending signal. PID: 8650 SIG: 9
```

here is the relevant code part(as to my knowledge :/ ).

```
preview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public  boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //get the Touch pointer count

                int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                int action=event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
                // if two fingers, take the picture and get the coordinates 
                if(pointerCount==2){


                    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){


                        int pointerIndex0 = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(0));
                        // Get the 1st pointer's current position
                        float x0 = event.getX(pointerIndex0);
                        float y0 = event.getY(pointerIndex0);
                        Log.d(TAG, "X0= "+x0 + " Y0=" + y0);
                        int pointerIndex1 = event.findPointerIndex(event.getPointerId(1));
                        // Get the 2nd pointer's current position
                        float x1 = event.getX(pointerIndex1);
                        float y1 = event.getY(pointerIndex1);
                        Log.d(TAG, "X1= "+x1 + " Y1=" + y1);

                        if (safeToTakePicture) {
                            safeToTakePicture = false;
                            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback); 

                        }

                    }

                    //preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                    prvw=0;

                }


                //else, focus only
                else if(pointerCount==1 && action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                    preview.camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {

                        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                            if(success){
                                Log.d(TAG,"focused success");
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }               
                return true;
            }



        });

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(prvw==1)
            finish();
        else
            onCreate(null);
    }
    public void onResume(){

        onCreate(null);
    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {


                //create the directory 
                String state = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/CamOverlay";

                File folder = new File(state);
                boolean success = true;
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    success = folder.mkdirs();
                }
                if(!success)
                    Log.d(TAG,"directory creation failed");

                // write to local sandbox file system
                // outStream =
                // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
                // Or write to sdcard

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(state+"/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));

                outStream.write(data);

                outStream.close();

                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
            safeToTakePicture=true;
        }
    };

}
```

Can somebody please explain me what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advanced.. :)

Comment: Please put your comment saying line 65 on your code

Comment: @Nabin
preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback,rawCallback,jpegCallback);
is on the line 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared this out.. :) if any one has the same problem I'll point out my mistake.

i used "down touch action" on single touch event and "2nd finger action up" on a multi_touch event. if the user did a double finger tap, the camera tries to do the both work and the app crashes.